# Disable interactivity in dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a number of bar charts created using `dc.js`.

In the default behavior, the user can click+drag on any of them to update the crossfilter. How can I make a chart "display-only"? That is, the chart will update when other components update the crossfilter, but the user can't select data in the "display-only" chart to update the crossfilter.

Comment: [brushOn](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.coordinateGridMixin+brushOn) ?

Comment: That definitely works, thanks! Is there a way to disable all the other interactivity as well (e.g., the bars highlighting when the user mouses over them)?

Comment: Nothing built in, I don't think. You could use a renderlet to disable the event listeners. Or you may be able to disable all mouse events with css pointer-events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events