# DC js composite chart tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, dc.js

I've plotted multiple charts linked together using dc & crossfilter js.
One last chart is a composite chart (bar and line) I'm not able to get the tooltip properly on it.

Currently, in the form of tooltip, it shows : During [object object], P1[object object]

(During and P1 are my dimensions)

My code :

```
//Composite chart to show 2 metrics
    chart4
    .width(990) // (optional) define chart width, :default = 200
    .height(200) // (optional) define chart height, :default = 200
    .transitionDuration(500) // (optional) define chart transition duration, :default = 500
    // (optional) define margins
    .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40})
    .dimension(dateDimension) // set dimension
    .group(rechfreqGroup) // set group
    // (optional) whether chart should rescale y axis to fit data, :default = false
    .elasticY(true)
    // (optional) when elasticY is on whether padding should be applied to y axis domain, :default=0
    .yAxisPadding(100)
    // (optional) whether chart should rescale x axis to fit data, :default = false
    //.elasticX(true)
    // (optional) when elasticX is on whether padding should be applied to x axis domain, :default=0
    .xAxisPadding(500)
    // define x scale
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    // (optional) render horizontal grid lines, :default=false
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    // (optional) render vertical grid lines, :default=false
    .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
    // compose sub charts, currently composite chart only supports line chart & bar chart
    ._rangeBandPadding(1) //workaround to fix visual stuff (dc js issues)
    .compose([

        dc.barChart(chart4).group(rechrevGroup).gap(2).centerBar(true).valueAccessor(function (p) {
        return p.value.count > 0 ? p.value.rechtotal / p.value.count : 0;
        }),
        // you can even include stacked bar chart or line chart in a composite chart
        dc.lineChart(chart4).group(rechfreqGroup).useRightYAxis(true).colors('#000000').valueAccessor(function (p) {
        return p.value.count > 0 ? p.value.rechfreq / p.value.count : 0;
        })
    ])
    // (optional) whether this chart should generate user interactive brush to allow range
    // selection, :default=true.
    .brushOn(true);
```

What am I missing here? Should I use d3.tip here to solve these issues?
Any approach/feedback is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever your reduction creates objects instead of straight values, you will need to specify a `.title` function in order to get the built-in tooltips to work properly.

This is because the default title function just prints the key and value.

[From the `.title` documentation](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.baseMixin+title):

```
// default title function just return the key
chart.title(function(d) { return d.key + ': ' + d.value; });
```

Actually it's a little bit smarter:

```
var _title = function (d) {
    return _chart.keyAccessor()(d) + ': ' + _chart.valueAccessor()(d);
};
```

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/base-mixin.js#L45-L47

Note that by default, titles are shared from the composite chart down to the child charts (depending on [shareTitle](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.compositeChart+shareTitle)). The tricky thing to consider here is that the function is defined in the parent chart, so if the titles are shared, the function will use the `keyAccessor` and `valueAccessor` of the parent, which is why your `valueAccessor`s on the children are having no effect.

Comment: I have added ".title" functions in my bar and line charts,  but the tool-tip is still not showing. Code snippet :  .title(function(d) { return d.key + ": " + d.value.rechtotal ; })  . Please let me know what I am doing wrong again

Comment: I thought you said it was showing the wrong thing before. Now it is not showing at all?

Comment: I forgot to note that `.title` must be specified before `.compose` (yay). As always, you can stick a `console.log` or a breakpoint into your title function if you think it is producing bad values or crashing...

Comment: Another quick question : I have a composite chart and I want to disable crossfiltering and make it only viewing graph. Can I do this simply by brush. (Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302885/disable-interactivity-in-dc-js ) . Turning brush off is also not working, actually.

Comment: Setting `.brushOn(false)` on the parent disables the brush for me - see e.g. [this example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/composite.html). Is there some other interaction you're trying to disable?